# How to update the FIX 5.0 tag 528 data dictionary to include values provided by the exchange

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

We are currently using Quickfix/J and using FIX 5.0 sp1. Tag 528 replaced tag 47 which has the values we wanted but tag 47 is depracated and the current values we have in FIX 5.0 are the following:

Valid values:

A = Agency

G = Proprietary

I = Individual

P = Principal (Note for CMS purposes, "Principal" includes "Proprietary")

R = Riskless Principal

W = Agent for Other Member

The exchange wants us to add these to the data dictionary.

Ø  528 OrderCapacity N Specifies the capacity of the firm
placing the order.

- NASDAQ Defined *

S – Institutional
G – Group
O – Other
M – Market Maker
L – Related Party
E – Error
T – Tax Exempt
D – Special Account Retail
F – Special Account Institutional

Can you please guide on how to do this update?

This is the class for tag 528.  Is it possible to create an extension of the tag 528? Can you share how it is done?

```
public class OrderCapacity extends CharField {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 20050617;

    public static final int FIELD = 528;
    public static final char AGENCY = 'A';
    public static final char PROPRIETARY = 'G';
    public static final char INDIVIDUAL = 'I';
    public static final char PRINCIPAL = 'P';
    public static final char RISKLESS_PRINCIPAL = 'R';
    public static final char AGENT_FOR_OTHER_MEMBER = 'W';

    public OrderCapacity() {
        super(528);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect your question to be answered if you don't tell us what you actually tried and what the results were.

Comment: I advise you to stop this course of action immediately.  You NEED to update your DD xml file to match your counterparty's expectations exactly.  The engine needs this DD to parse incoming messages.

Beyond this: your question is difficult to follow because we don't know what message this is, and whether you are sending or receiving it.  But frankly, none of that is important until you have a correct DD.  **Create an updated DD.  Do it now.  Stop doing other things.**

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier, yes that's the long-term plan is to have a DD XML.  What we are looking for is a temporary workaround. We are receiving 528=L and because we don't have it in our field 528 the trade message is getting rejected.

Comment: Aha!  You finally told us your actual situation!  The fastest way to fix this issue is to update your DD XML file, at least for the L message.  The engine uses the XML file to parse all incoming messages, so this is actually, for real, what you absolutely must do first.  You don't need a custom class right now.  You can use generic msg.GetString(tag) readers to extract field values in your application.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier , using msg.GetString(tag) , will that be msg.GetString(528=L) ?

Comment: I believe it's just just `msg.getString(528)`, which should return `L` in your example.  (I'm a little rusty on the Java port's syntax, but that should be close)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the QF/n docs for customizing the data dictionary](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html).

Even though that site is for the C# QF port, the data dictionary files are the  same and the instructions should be good for you.

If you need further help, please ask new questions that are more specific.

Comment: We are not using data dictionary xml files.  I created classes.  What I did is create an extended OrderCapacityModel class that will include the basic values from the OrderCapacity class for field 528.   Will this work?

Comment: That is vital information that should have been in your question (and it's still not enough).

Comment: You are not using the dictionary but want to know how to extend it?

Comment: This is what we have. public class OrderCapacity extends CharField {

static final long serialVersionUID = 20050617;

public static final int FIELD = 528;
public static final char AGENCY = 'A';
public static final char PROPRIETARY = 'G';
public static final char INDIVIDUAL = 'I';
public static final char PRINCIPAL = 'P';
public static final char RISKLESS_PRINCIPAL = 'R';
public static final char AGENT_FOR_OTHER_MEMBER = 'W';

public OrderCapacity() {
super(528);
}

Comment: The exchange said you have to add some more fields in this class, but how can we add or override this class in my java code?  I believe the exchange wants the values from tag 47 to carry over to tag 528.

or is there any way that how can add these more values which is provided by 

 

S – Institutional

G – Group

O – Other

M – Market Maker

 L – Related Party

E – Error

T – Tax Exempt

D – Special Account Retail

F – Special Account Institutional

Please anyone help us how can we resolve this 528 Tag error and successfully send the order on FIX.

Comment: Put this info in your question!  It doesn't make any sense to put it in this answer.  (Are you new to StackOverflow?)

Comment: Yes, Grant. New in stockoverflow. I only started using it for about a month. I am more on the management side but trying to help out resolve an issue with my tech team.

Comment: @ChristophJohn , yes, can we extend without using the dictionary? We will plan to build a new QF/J using the data dictionary. Thanks.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier , I revised the question and put the vital information.

Comment: @ChristophJohn , I have the java class in the question section.  Could you please advise on how to add an extension to tag 528?